# Refit API Client - Mix Body and Queryparameters in single object

Tags: asp.net, refit

When using the Refit REST Library to build a client targeting an asp.net based api is it possible to mix Query and Body items in a single Custom Object?

Example Asp.Net Route

```
[Route("documents/{id}")]
public void PostDocument(int id, [FromBody] document)
```

Example Refit Client and Request Object showing desired mixing of Body and Query definition in single object

```
[Post("/documents/{document.id}")]
Task PostDocument(PostDocumentRequest request);
```

```
public class PostDocumentRequest 
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public [Query] DateTime? LocalDateTime { get;set; }
    public [Body] Document Document { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling your example might not fully be in line with your question which is throwing me off. Is your question if you can use properties from the input parameters in your query string? In your example the "{document.id}" part is confusing as there is no document defined anywhere